# Redirect ASP pages to a new URL

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis, asp-classic, redirect

Our old website was built using ASP and now we are using Wordpress (IIS) utilizing a sub-directory. All of the old ASP files are still in the root directory and I'd like to redirect all of these file extensions to our new Wordpress site because the old ASP files are causing 404 errors.

I'm having a real difficult time figuring out what to put in my web.config file so all the old ASP pages are redirected to our new home page.

Thanks

Comment: This may be what you are looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098632/seemingly-simple-redirect-in-iis-using-web-config-file

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the URL Rewriting extension for IIS ( http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite ) which can also perform regex-based redirections. Create a new rule that matches `(.+)\.asp` and redirects as appropriate.

I don't know if you just want to do a 'dumb' redirect from all `.asp`-URIs to your WordPress root, or if you want to intelligently redirect users from the old .asp pages to their new WordPress equivalents (this is a good idea as it means search engine results and previous links won't be broken, I'm sure you can imagine how frustrating it is to follow a link that doesn't go where the user expects).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't have access to our IIS server so I cannot install any extensions. Unfortunately, I need to perform the redirect via the web.config file.

Comment: All the rewrite engine "wizard" does is to write stuff to web.config, so if you have IIS on your own machine you can generate your rules there then copy and paste.

Comment: @John It still requires that the Rewrite module be installed on IIS, it isn't included by default.

Comment: @user965879 -- Pure classic ASP do not using web.config. It's for ASP.NET.

Comment: @Dai - Ah, I'd assumed it was included by default in dedicated server editions of Windows, but I guess it's just a case of hosting companies choosing to add it to their virtual server offerings.

Comment: @user965879 - web.config can be used to redirect files with any extension, so while it isn't part of Classic ASP, it can be used for URL redirecting or rewriting involving files with the .asp extension, assuning of course that ASP.net is enabled in the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions, but because I don't have access to the server, my only solution was to work with the web.config file. I simply added the following code and everything now works:

```
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
     <add wildcard="*.asp" destination="/" />
  </httpRedirect>
```